# Visual Studio 2013/15 MVC web application

Tags: office-365, visual-studio, mvc

I'm trying this articles\tutorials to get an MVC portal going but none seems to match.

Does anyone know a tutorial that works?

Checked this:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/officeapps/2013/07/09/introducing-mvc-support-for-apps-for-sharepoint/
on prem and Online.

The `autohosted` option is no longer available. when I hit F5, I get an error. articles don't mention details like disable "deploy".

Do I need to be on a SharePoint VM to develop a portal for a Online SP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me clarify some things first:

1. You are correct, Auto-Hosted is no longer supported. If you get the newest Office Developer Tools for Visual Studio 2013 or 2015, you will see the option to create an Auto-Hosted App has been removed. You can get the latest tools using the Web Platform Installer.
2. You do not need a SharePoint VM to build an App (also known as an Add-In) that targets SharePoint Online.

The question of how to build a Provider-Hosted App using ASP.NET MVC is covered in this session from the Microsoft Conference 2014: [Developing Cloud-Hosted Apps with MVC5](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC419).